# Is it safe to sell unique low-level weapons?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I have found several unique (purple) low-level weapons. They are quickly outclassed by more mundane high-level gear, but I'm afraid that there may be some upgrade process that would make these cool-looking weapons viable again. Is there anything like this in the late game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an upgrade system, but not in a way that you might make low level weapons very powerful again. Each item can have upgrade slots in which you can place a crafted/found item that will add a stat to the item. For example, a staff might have a Handle, Blade and Rune upgrade slot.

This does not make up for the lower level item's low base stats, such as Armor or Damage, though. It can drastically improve an item, but generally the generic crafted items of the higher levels will be more effective to use.

I do seem to recall that most unique (purple) items did not have upgrade slots, but I could be wrong on that account. They should show up on the tooltip if they have.

Answer (score 0):

So far the only negative I have found in selling unique weapons is the original Armour I sold. Now I cannot make my character look that way again to the specific only to that person armour.